# Scrapy downloads the HTML template rather than the page source

Tags: python, html, templates, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy, so forgive this stupid question.

```py
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy_proj.scrapy_proj.items import PageSourceLoc, ItemField
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.http.response import Response
from scrapy import Selector


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'websources'
    start_urls = ["https://www.acquistinretepa.it/opencms/opencms/scheda_altri_bandi.html?idBando=b11f430208bfa91e"]

    def parse(self, response: Response, **kwargs):
        page_info = PageSourceLoc()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
        print(response.text)
```

when it comes to see the details of the page, I found elements related to the template used, such as:

```
{{numeroVerdePA}}, {{numeroVerdeIM}}
```

Those should have been filled with the current values of the web page. Is it there some Scrapy setting I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. When these kind of wired error happen, you just have to use Selenium (https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) and parse the page with that accordingly.